# Get a list of links with specific pattern from list of many links

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using BeautifulSoup and requests to scrape and parse some data from a website.

I have gotten to a point where I have an output list of links from the website I am scraping, but I need to narrow this list down to only the links I need.

Here is a photo of the output for my code:
[image]

I only need the links with the pattern `/cpc/datasheet/#####`

I have tried `re.findall()`, `re.search()`, `filter()`, and a few other options with no luck.

Comment: Please paste your full code here. Do not post images as code

Comment: Please dont post picture of textual output, copy paste it instead. Pictures are terrible medium for sharing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `startswith()` method check if the link startswith `/cpc/datasheet/` and append it to a list:

```
links = [link for link in soup.find_all('a') if str(link.get('href')).startswith('/cpc/datasheet/')]
```

Or:

```
out = []
for tag in soup.find_all('a'):
    link = tag.get('href')
    if str(link).startswith('/cpc/datasheet/'):
        print(link)
        out.append(link)
```